# AVMutableAudioMix volume of multiple tracks not working correctly

Tags: ios, audio, video, avfoundation

I have a simple editor that concatenates local video files and underlays it with music also from a local file.

I'm creating a composition and composition tracks and add the videos a/v tracks to them:

```
NSMutableArray *audioInputParams = [NSMutableArray array];
AVMutableComposition *composition = [NSMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

for (AVURLAsset *asset in assets) {
    AVAssetTrack *audioTrack = [asset compatibleTrackForCompositionTrack:compositionAudioTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [asset compatibleTrackForCompositionTrack:compositionVideoTrack];

    // compositionAudioTrack insert audioTrack
    // compositionVideoTrack insert videoTrack
```

This all works fine. The resulting video cuts perfectly in sound and video.

In the UI is a slider that crossfades between the original video sound and the music sound. The slider goes from 0 to 1, as AVs volumes do as well.

I use the sliders value minus one for each videos volume and for the music the value as it is.

```
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioMixParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:audioTrack];
    [audioMixParameters setVolume:1.0 - [slider value] atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams addObject:audioMixParameters];
}

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionMusicTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVURLAsset *musicAsset;
AVAssetTrack *musicTrack = [musicAsset compatibleTrackForCompositionTrack:compositionMusicTrack];

[compositionMusicTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [composition duration])
                               ofTrack:musicTrack
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero
                                 error:nil];

AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *musicInputParameter = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:musicTrack];
[musicInputParameter setVolume:[slider value] atTime:kCMTimeZero];

[audioInputParams addObject:musicInputParameter];

AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioMix setInputParameters:audioInputParams];
```

When I now use the audio mix, either for playback or for rendering, the audio mix does not work. When I set the videos volume to 1, it's not hearable. When setting to zero, I can hear it.

And no matter what value I set to the music, it is full on the output.

I also tried setting the trackID, which didn't do either. Also, it's no slider issue, I tried hardcoding various float values and it turned out to be not working.

Now I don't get why this would behave like this. It's totally odd and not explainable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if you are adding the audio mix in the correct objects, the `audiomix` is not added to the composition itself. To see the effects of the audio mix you need to add it to an instance of `AVPlayerItem` when doing playback, or add it to an `AVAssetExportSession` if you are exporting. Have a look at the [AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH8-SW1)

Comment: "When I now use the audio mix, either for playback or for rendering, [...]" please properly read the question. It had to do something with the order or so, but I solved it already, so I'm gonna delete the question

Comment: Sorry I missed that.. But please provide the answer on how you solved this issue, AVFoundation is very complex and this question might be of use to others including me, since thats how I got to your question in the first place, I was having similar issues with audiomix.

Comment: Wiuld be better, you're right. I'll need to lookup the actual issue, it was something wierd. Give me a bit time for that ;)

Comment: Can I get your answer ?please.I have the same question too.